# Flask/SQLAlchemy error inserting record to database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am unable to create a new record in the database using the user input from the html form via post request. I get an error message "Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

```
@app.route("/create_profile", methods=['GET','POST'])
def create_profile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      n = request.form['name']
      z = request.form['zipcode']
      i1 = request.form['dancing']
      i2 = request.form['football']
      i3 = request.form['art']
      u = User(name=n, zipcode=z, inter1=i1, inter2=i2, inter3=i3 )
      db.session.add(u)
      db.session.commit
    return render_template("create_profile.html")
```

Comment: `db.session.commit` should be `db.session.commit()`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Why not write the answer? I'm tempted to steal it from you :P

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by @BurhanKhalidin the comment, you should add back your missing brackets when invoke commit() function: `db.session.commit()`